# How to add web app icon png to root document folder?

Tags: theming, 8

> To specify an icon for the entire website (every page on the website),
>   place an icon file in PNG format in the root document folder called
>   `apple-touch-icon.png`

Exactly how do I do this in Drupal 8?

Yes, my site adds lots of different touch icons to the `html.html.twig` template in an assortment of different sizes for Android, Apple, and MS Tiles but all this does not have precisely the effect I want for my web app. [For further info see Apple docs here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Answer (score 1):

> place an icon file in PNG format in the root document folder called apple-touch-icon.png

Literally that - put a file called apple-touch-icon.png in your web root. Drupal doesn't affect static files, it won't interfere.

Comment: Which of the Drupal docroot; the `sites/default`; or `sites/my_multisite.com` folder? Obviously not the Drupal docroot as each web app is different.

Comment: Yes, the docroot for your web site. It's better practice to keep them in sites/* as you mentioned, but you can't do what you're asking in the question and do that at the same time..unless you perhaps use some .htaccess directives based on the hostname to rewrite /apple-touch-icon.png to the relevant manually-uploaded file under sites/*. But this is kind of the reason those meta tags exist in the first place, so you can use the UI to upload files and not have to worry about doing it manually. It might be better to concentrate on fixing the current meta tag method to get your desired result

Comment: Still confused !:-) as I understand it: a) nginx thinks my docroot is where Drupal's `index.php` is. b) The Drupal admin UI only allows me to upload a favicon c) the 'current meta tag method' links only seem to tell IOS about a web app *page* and not a *site* which has to be in 'the docroot' ...